# How to insert FLAG(0x02, 0x01, 0x06) into BLE advertisement with Bluez's example

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I am trying to make fully customized BLE advertisement with bluez.

My code is based on the official example:
https://github.com/luetzel/bluez/blob/master/test/example-advertisement

The only change is the payload of advertisement:

```
class TestAdvertisement(Advertisement):

def __init__(self, bus, index, ble_data):
    Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, 'peripheral')
    ble_data=[0x40, 0x02, 0xc4, 0x09, 0x03, 0xbf, 0x13]
    self.add_service_data('FCD2', ble_data)
    self.add_local_name('my_name')
```

From my nRF app scanner, I can see the local name and the uuid D2FC correctly.

While I need to insert FLAG(0x02, 0x01, 0x06), I can't find a way to do this with this official example.

I was using `self.add_data()` which caused format error.

I think probably `Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, 'peripheral')` made some default FLAG, but I am not sure.

Please guide me how to insert the FLAG. Thanks.